# change hadoop use of directory /dev/mapper, no space for root

Tags: hadoop, centos

i used the command `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/yarn` to execute the map-reduce program.

Every time I run the program, the root partition is going to be full occupied.

How to alter the directory Hadoop uses, except for `/dev/mapper`?

I want to change the default directory to /home, where and how?

[image: use of root partition]

Comment: You only have 2 filesystems, `/` and `/home`. Are you attempting to use `/home` for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, I want to use /home instead. I want to know how to change the setting. :)